# How do Firestore (authentication) rules see cloud function reads/writes and trigger function reads/writes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm at a point where I need to start setting up rules for my data in firestore. However, in my web app, although I query data directly from Firestore, I almost never write directly to it. All writes are done via cloud functions:

```js
exports.post_content = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    db.collection(...)...().add(..)
        .then(...)
        .catch(...)
});
```

There are also several instances where data is written via trigger functions:

```js
exports.on_content_write = functions.firestore.document('abc/xyz/...').onCreate(..);
```

Almost every doc or tutorial I've found on firestore rules assumes that data is being written (or read) by a web user who either is or is not authenticated. But which 'user' is firestore checking when a write is coming via an http request (such as `post_content`)? Since post_content, itself is called by a client (via the web or curl or whatever), are those credentials passed on to firestore?

What about when functions are automatically triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no user implied for HTTP requests.  When you use the Firebase Admin SDK (or any server SDK for Firestore), you are initalizing it with a service account that will have full control over the database, completely bypassing all security rules.

If you are hoping to simulate a write as an an authenticated user in code running in Cloud Functions (or any other backend), that is not possible with Firestore.  The best you can do is pass an auth ID token from the client to the function, [verify it with the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), and decide in your code if you want to allow the write for that user.  You just won't be able to use security rules in this situation.